# Accessing object in iframe using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, iframe, web-scraping

To the point:

I have successfully used VBA to do the following:

- Login to a website using getElementsByName
- Select parameters for the report that will be generated (using getelementsby...)
- generating the report after selecting parameters which renders the resulting dataset into an iframe on the same page

**Important to note - The website is client-side**

The above was the simple part, the difficult part is as below:

> **clicking on a gif image within the iframe that exports the dataset to a csv**

I have tried the following:

```
Dim idoc As HTMLDocument
Dim iframe As HTMLFrameElement
Dim iframe2 As HTMLDocument

Set idoc = objIE.document
Set iframe = idoc.all("iframename")
Set iframe2 = iframe.contentDocument

    Do Until InStr(1, objIE.document.all("iframename").contentDocument.innerHTML, "img.gif", vbTextCompare) = 0
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

To give some context to the logic above -

- I accessed the main frame
- i accessed the iframe by its name element
- i accessed the content within the iframe
- **I attempted to find the gif image that needs to be clicked to export to csv**

It is at this line that it trips up saying "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Also tried accessing the iframe gif by the a element and href attribute but this totally failed. I also tried grabbing the image from its source URL but all this does it take me to the page the image is from.

**note: the iframe does not have an ID and strangely the gif image does not have an "onclick" element/event**

> **Final consideration - attempted scraping the iframe using R**

accessing the HTML node of the iframe was simple, however trying to access the attributes of the iframe and subsequently the nodes of the table proved unsuccessful. All it returned was "Character(0)"

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

Blah <-read_html("web address redacted") %>%
  html_nodes("#iframe")%>%
  html_nodes("#img")%>%
  html_attr("#src")%>%
  #read_html()%>%
  head()
Blah
```

As soon as a i include read_html the following error returns on the script:

Error in if (grepl("<|>", x)) { : argument is of length zero

I suspect this is referring to the Character(0)

Appreciate any guidance here!

Many Thanks,

> HTML

```
<div align="center"> 
    <table id="table1" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"> &nbsp;</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="6"> 
                    <a href="href redacted">
                        <img src="img.gif" width="38" height="38" border="0" align="right">
                    </a>
                    <strong>x - </strong>
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the HTML code around the gif. You already can access the iframe via contentDocument, right? All needed now is the HTMl around the GIF. Then we can see

Comment: @MacroMarc which part of the html do you need to see?

Comment: is it the href?

Comment: parent elements of gif and gif itself...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is sometimes tricky with `iframes`. Based on `html` you provided I have created this example. Which works locally, but would it work for you as well?

To get to the `IFrame` the `frames` collection can be used. Hope you know the `name` of the `IFrame`?

```
Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set iframeDoc = doc.frames("iframename").document
```

Then to go the the `image` we can use `querySelector` method e.g. like this:

```
Dim img As MSHTML.HTMLImg
Set img = iframeDoc.querySelector("div table[id='table1'] tbody tr td a[href^='https://stackoverflow.com'] img")
```

The selector `a[href^='https://stackoverflow.com']` selects `anchor` which has an `href` attribute which starts with given text. [The `^` denotes the beginning](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp).

Then when we have the image just a simple call to `click` on its parent which is the desired `anchor`. HTH

---

Complete example:

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub Demo()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String
    
    url = "file:///C:/Users/dusek/Documents/My Web Sites/mainpage.html"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    Set doc = ie.document
    
    Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set iframeDoc = doc.frames("iframename").document
    If iframeDoc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "IFrame with name 'iframename' was not found."
        ie.Quit
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim img As MSHTML.HTMLImg
    Set img = iframeDoc.querySelector("div table[id='table1'] tbody tr td a[href^='https://stackoverflow.com'] img")
    If img Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Image element within iframe was not found."
        ie.Quit
        Exit Sub
    Else
        img.parentElement.Click
    End If
    
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

> Main page HTML used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>x -</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe name="iframename" src="iframe1.html">
</iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

> IFrame HTML used (saved as file `iframe1.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center"> 
    <table id="table1" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"> &nbsp;</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="6"> 
                    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902558/accessing-object-in-iframe-using-vba">
                        <img src="img.gif" width="38" height="38" border="0" align="right">
                    </a>
                    <strong>x - </strong>
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

> BTW, The frame may be referenced by it's index also `doc.frames(0).document`. Thanks to Paulo Bueno.

Comment: Okay so successfully managed to get it to click on the gif! thanks! however... the gif exports a csv file that contains the data within the iframe. The export is empty... nothing in the csv but there is in the iframe i can see

Comment: So the difficult part is not done yet :). After `click` on the `anchor` the data which are loaded inside of that `iframe` shoud be exported to `csv-file`. And you see the data in the `iframe` but after `click` on `anchor` the `csv-file` is empty. Do I understood it correctly?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I get a web browser prompt to open or save as the file. I open it manually but file is empty

Comment: You have to examine the request e.g. via [IE Developer Tools - F12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbbjL_Uir24). Compare request in the case when it works with case when you click the anchor programmatically. Have a look on `query string` etc and try to find the differences. But without seeing it directly it is hard to say.

Comment: what exactly do you need to see to solve this? there are lots of areas in the DOM explorer/F12 Tools

Comment: You should examine the `Request` the browser sends to server, when the `CSV-file` is requested. It is on the `Network-Tab`. So you can maybe found why it works when clicked _manually_ and why it not working when clicked _programatically_.

Comment: Okay i inspected the difference between manual and programmatic. Very informative way of debugging! When manually clicked, the "Name/Path" is the FULL href link whereas when programmatically clicked the "Name/Path" is only the anchor element of the href (not the full path). Second difference is "content type" - manual is application/x-csv and programmatic is text/html

Comment: when i say "anchor element"  i mean similar to the example above where you have "selector a[href^='https://stackoverflow.com']".

Comment: Could you post these informations here e.g. like screen shots? In some censored form so the clients informations stay hidden? I don't know what is the cause. Maybe some javascript runs when clicked manually because it reacts on e.g. `mouse-up` event (which is not present when programatically calling `click` only)?

Comment: do you want screenshot of what is displayed on the "Network" tab? for when it is programmatically click vs manually clicked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148627/discussion-between-dee-and-mo-h).

Comment: So we moved the discussion to chat, but now we have to write comments again to remind, that in chat is new post, well thats _funny_ :). Or do I miss something?

Comment: BTW, The frame may be referenced by it's index also `doc.frames(0).document`. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would expand on the answer already given.

In the case of Internet Explorer you may have one of two common situations to handle regarding iframes.

1. src of iframe is subject to same origin policy restrictions:

---

The iframe src has a different origin to the landing page in which case, due to [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), attempts to access it will yield **access denied**.

**Resolution:**

Consider using selenium basic to automate a different browser such as Chrome where CORS is allowed/you can switch to the iframe and continue working with the iframe document

**Example:**

```
Option Explicit
'download selenium https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0
'Ensure latest applicable driver e.g. ChromeDriver.exe in Selenium folder
'VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to selenium type library
Public Sub Example()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Const URL As String = "https://www.rosterresource.com/mlb-roster-grid/"
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("iframe") '< pass the iframe element as the identifier argument
        ' .SwitchToDefaultContent ''to go back to parent document.
        Stop '<== delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

2. src of iframe is not subject to same origin policy restrictions:

---

**Resolution:**

The methods as detailed in answer already given. Additionally, you can extract the src of the `iframe` and `.Navigate2` that to access

```
.Navigate2 .document.querySelector("iframe").src
```

If you only want to work with the contents of the iframe then simply do your initial `.Navigate2` the `iframe src` and don't even visit the initial landing page

**Example:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub NavigateUsingSrcOfIframe()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5978065"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        
        .Navigate2 .document.querySelector("iframe").src
        
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop '<== delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

3. iframe in ShadowRoot

---

An unlikely case might be an `iframe` in [shadowroot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot). You should really have [one or the other](https://blog.logrocket.com/discovering-the-shadow-dom-e541d74aefb3) and not one within the other.

[image]

**Resolution:**

In that case you need an additional accessor of

```
Element.shadowRoot.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument
```

where `Element` is your parent element with `shadowRoot` attached. This method will only work if the `shadowRoot` `mode` is set to `Open`.

Side note:

A nice selenium based example, using `ExecuteScript` to return `shadowRoot` is given here: [How Do I Access Elements in the Shadow DOM using Selenium in VBA?](https://youtu.be/phYGCGXGtEw)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers given:

If you're ok with using a DLL and rewrite your code, you can run Microsoft's Edge browser (a Chrome-based browser) with VBA. With that you can do almost anything you want. Note however, that access to the DOM is performed by javascript, not by an object like Dim IE As New InternetExplorer. Look at the VBA sample and you'll get the grasp.

https://github.com/peakpeak-github/libEdge

Sidenote: Samples for C# and C++ are also included.