# VBA with Excel and IE: Can't get the source right source code?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, slp

I'm currently trying to automate my IE at work with VBA and Excel, because we have some repetitive tasks to complete in an SAP System which is called within the Internet Explorer.
So far I am able to start IE and navigate to the starting page of our System.

I looked on the source code from the Sap System to search for an id from a div (lets say its 'SampleID'). But if I try to click it via VBA I only get returned 'nothing'. So I tried to print out the source code via VBA Debug.Print to look at the problem. And here's the thing:

The source code that gets printed is completely different from the Website's Source Code. In the printed code for example is a iframe that I can't find in the website source code. So that's the reason I can't find my div and any other objects, because they are not in the code that VBA is searching through.
Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? Why are the source codes completely different?

```
Sub stgGo(){
 Dim i As Long
 Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
 Dim objElement As Object
 Dim objCollection As Object  

 Set IE = New InternetExplorer
 IE.Visible = True
 IE.Navigate ("URL")

'waiting 10 seconds to be really sure javascript is ready
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) 

'printing out the false source code
 Debug.Print strHTML = myIE.Document.body.innerHTML 

 Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
 i = 0
 While i < objCollection.Length
  If objCollection(i).ID = "SampleID" Then
   objCollection(i).Click
  End If
  i = i + 1
 Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this missing `"` after `div` your typo or the original script error?

Comment: just a typo. i get no compiler errors :)

Comment: Why are you search the collection and not using `Dim div As HTMLDivElement` and  `Set div = IE.document.getElementById("SampleID")`.  Are there multiple elements withthe same ID?

Comment: You are right, that would be more  reasonable. But it should work like this too

Comment: You cannot exit from a While ... Wend loop unless you use a GoTo. Maybe switch to a For ... Next so you can Exit For after the click.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't even search the right source code, so it wont work with a For...Next either. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: Then maybe [search this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5Diframe+div) for *vba iframe div* and come up with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902558/accessing-object-in-iframe-using-vba).

Comment: Don't use "view source" for this - open up your browser's Developer tools (F12) and use the tools there to view the as-rendered HTML. Or in IE just right-click the element you want to work with and select "inspect element"

Comment: Well I dont have the source code for the page you trying to work with, but i normally would something like this:
`Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
While i < objCollection.Length
  If objCollection(i).Name = "ctl00$MainContent$txtUsername" Then
   objCollection(i).Value = "MyUsername" 
  End If
i = i + 1
Wend`

Comment: Its more or less the same as you do, but I run into problems when I use "div". I would also normally wait for the while..wend to be complete before I `.click`. you could store the SampleID in a new object `Set objElement = objCollection(i)` and when your while..wend is done I would `objElement.Click`