# Click text input box based on id

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping

I am currently trying to click the following text input box based on its id: dp1571754895218 in VBA

```
<input title="INVOICEDATE" class="half-filter hasDatepicker" id="dp1571754895218" style="margin-right: 2px; opacity: 1;" type="text" placeholder="From" data-bind="attr: { placeholder: 'From', title: $data.Key, 'data-tabgroup': 'itemlistfilter', 'data-tabgroupindex': ($index() + 1) }, datepicker: $data.Range.From, datepickerOptions: { dateFormat: $root.jQformatDate($data.Format) }, style: { 'opacity': $parent.multiSearchOn() ? '0.3' : '1' }" data-tabgroup="itemlistfilter" data-tabgroupindex="7">
```

What I have tried so far is this:

```
Dim date1 As Object
Set html = ie.document
Set date1 = html.getElementById("dp1571754895218")
For Each l In date1
    If l.className = "half-filter hasDatepicker" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

But I keep getting the following error: **Run-time error '424': Object required**.
I already have the correct references too. What am I doing incorrectly?

Edit: For QHarr, here are both html codes
placeholder = To:

```html
<input title="INVOICEDATE" class="half-filter hasDatepicker" id="dp1571841444746" style="opacity: 1;" type="text" placeholder="To" data-bind="attr: { placeholder: 'To', title: $data.Key, 'data-tabgroup': 'itemlistfilter', 'data-tabgroupindex': ($index() + 1.1) }, datepicker: $data.Range.To, datepickerOptions: { dateFormat: $root.jQformatDate($data.Format) }, style: { 'opacity': $parent.multiSearchOn() ? '0.3' : '1' }" data-tabgroup="itemlistfilter" data-tabgroupindex="7.1">
```

Placeholder = From:

```html
<input title="INVOICEDATE" class="half-filter hasDatepicker" id="dp1571841444745" style="margin-right: 2px; opacity: 1;" type="text" placeholder="From" data-bind="attr: { placeholder: 'From', title: $data.Key, 'data-tabgroup': 'itemlistfilter', 'data-tabgroupindex': ($index() + 1) }, datepicker: $data.Range.From, datepickerOptions: { dateFormat: $root.jQformatDate($data.Format) }, style: { 'opacity': $parent.multiSearchOn() ? '0.3' : '1' }" data-tabgroup="itemlistfilter" data-tabgroupindex="7">
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: On the "For each l In date1" line I get the error

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities (the first being the likely culprit then some other considerations are listed):

1) `getElementById` returns a single element so you do not `For Each` over. Simply do:

```
html.getElementById("dp1571754895218").click
```

2) The id may be dynamic. Then try using combination of `title` and `class`

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title=INVOICEDATE].hasDatepicker").click
```

No need for a loop

3) You do not have a long enough wait for the element to be present. Use a proper page load wait and a timed loop for the presence of the element

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, t As Date, ele As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10


    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "url"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.getElementById("dp1571754895218")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing

        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        ele.click

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

4) Your element is inside a [frame/iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902558/accessing-object-in-iframe-using-vba) which needs to be navigated first

---

EDIT:

Try:

```
ie.document.querySelector(".hasDatepicker[placeholder=To]").value = "ABC"
ie.document.querySelector(".hasDatepicker[placeholder=From]").value = "XYZ"
```

Comment: It says that the object doesn't support this property or method on the "ele.click" line

Comment: What is the result of debug.print typename(ele) ?

Comment: Ah so I took a look at your second line of code and you were right about the dynamic id. The problem with that though is that there are 2 datepickers, one that is $data.Range.From and the other is $data.Range.To. Do you know how I can distinguish the two? Because the 3rd solution you provided is a little difficult to incorporate into my macro for me.

Comment: Can you share the html for both? Use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html properly.

Comment: I put the two snippets in the question post :D. What I want to do is type in values into those areas. I thought clicking and then using Sendkeys (vba) to input values from Excel, but if there is a way to directly input these values without clicking, that would be great too.

Comment: getAttribute takes a value. It does not assign. So, are you saying you used my bottom edit to assign a value then read it to the sheet and got  "Tue Jan 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" ?

Comment: I just tried it now and still got that weird result

Comment: I can't see your screen so I don't know what you are doing :-( you need to tell me the steps you are doing to produce this.

Comment: What I am trying to do is input the From date and To date into the above html fields. I will be getting these dates from an excel doc. The dates have the format MM/DD/YYYY. Say the From date is in cells(1, 1). When I do ie.document.querySelector(".hasDatepicker[placeholder=To]").value = Cells(1,1).value, it autmatically inputs the date in that weird format. But if I do ie.document.querySelector(".hasDatepicker[placeholder=To]").value = "1/30/2018", it inputs it correctly. :(

Comment: try ie.document.querySelector(".hasDatepicker[placeholder=To]").value = Cells(1,1).value2

Comment: Or input as text e.g. ie.document.querySelector(".hasDatepicker[placeholder=To]").value = Format$(Cells(1,1).value, "mm/dd/yyyy")