# Vba to control pop up table in IE

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, dom

I want to click the radio button in table and fill value in box in below table

[image]

The table will pop up when I click one of this file link.
however my `HTMLdocument(HTMLDoc)` feel like broken when that happen.
My code dont work to click Ok on that table

Here is my code

```
Set IE2 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
apiShowWindow IE2.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE

'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
IE2.Visible = True
IE2.Visible = False
IE2.Visible = True

'Define URL
URL = "https://dgspj-prod.ptcmanaged.com/intellicus/core/SavedReportList.jsp?CATEGORYID="

'Navigate to URL
IE2.navigate URL

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE2.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until IE2.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

Set HTMLDoc = IE2.document

    'below not fulfilled in table
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("rdbSeparatorCustom").Click
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("TXT_CSV_COLUMN_SEPARATOR").Value = "~"
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("rdbEnclosureCustom").Click
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("TXT_CSV_COLUMN_ENCLOSURE").Value = ""

    HTMLDoc.querySelector("input[value='Ok']").Click 'not work
    HTMLDocDoc.getElementById("btnSubmit").Click 'not work too
```

Here is IE Html

```
<LABEL class=option-label style="MARGIN-LEFT: 42px"><INPUT onclick='fnEnableDisableControls(this,"ENCLOSURE","csv");' id=rdbEnclosureCustom type=radio value=CUSTOM name=CSV_COLUMN_ENCLOSURE_TYPE>Custom</LABEL>
<DIV class=win-btn-wpr><INPUT onclick=fnSetIsDirty();fnSubmit(); id=btnSubmit class="cssButton btn-blue" type=button value=Ok name=btnSubmit> <INPUT onclick=fnHideDiv() id=btnCancel class=cssButton type=button value=Cancel name=btnCancel> </DIV>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the VBA code can work well with the provided HTML code. Is there any error when you run the VBA code and in which line the error occures ? Could you give the HTML code which can **reproduce the issue**? I tested with the following VBA code and it can [click the radio button and the submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RtBq.gif):

```
Sub LOADIE()
Set IE2 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
IE2.Visible = True

'Define URL
URL = "http://test page"

'Navigate to URL
IE2.navigate URL

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE2.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until IE2.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

Set HTMLDoc = IE2.document

HTMLDoc.getElementById("rdbSeparatorCustom").Click
HTMLDoc.getElementById("TXT_CSV_COLUMN_SEPARATOR").Value = "test"
HTMLDoc.getElementById("rdbEnclosureCustom").Click
HTMLDoc.getElementById("TXT_CSV_COLUMN_ENCLOSURE").Value = "test"

HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnSubmit").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: vba itself dont give any error but function inside html seem cannot work.
i put the html code in here
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/i0mwmeu06yxe1ux/html%20code%20of%20form.txt?dl=0]

Comment: I tested with the html code you providing and changed the onclick function in the radio button to `console.log`, it can work well with the above vba code. I think the issue is *function inside html cannot work*, if the function can't be triggered without VBA, then it of course can't be triggered with VBA. Besides, is `HTMLDocDoc` a type error in your VBA code? I think it should be `HTMLDoc`.

Comment: Besides, you should pay attention if the pop up table is in an iframe. If it is in an iframe, you can't access the objects directly with `docement.getElementById`. You should reach the iframe first then you can reach the elements. For detailed information, you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902558/accessing-object-in-iframe-using-vba/44952913#44952913).